# VirtualBox v 5.2.18 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - vboxadd-service and nginx not loading

Tags: virtualbox, nginx

I would like to ask for some support :) I'm still an Ubuntu newbie however I've been running an Atomic-Toolkit for some time and, so far, it's been working without any issues. I'm using it for all type of Media Management etc. However after a recent update to the 18.04.1 LTS Version of Ubuntu, my shared folders for the VBox Guest are not mounting nor the nginx service is loading.

I've check quite a lot of forums and responses but it seems nobody has a similar issue. I've been trying to restart the vboxadd-service.service and the nginx one but the errors are as follows:

**vboxadd-service.service**

```
Sep 11 12:45:07 mmonkey systemd[1]: Starting vboxadd-service.service...
Sep 11 12:45:08 mmonkey vboxadd-service[1432]: vboxadd-service.sh: Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service.
Sep 11 12:45:09 mmonkey vboxadd-service.sh[1511]: VirtualBox Guest Addition service started.
Sep 11 12:45:09 mmonkey systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 11 12:45:09 mmonkey systemd[1]: vboxadd-service.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 11 12:45:09 mmonkey systemd[1]: Failed to start vboxadd-service.service.
```

**nginx service**

```
Sep 11 12:44:51 mmonkey systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 11 12:45:00 mmonkey nginx[1022]: nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" dire
Sep 11 12:45:00 mmonkey nginx[1022]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Sep 11 12:45:00 mmonkey systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 11 12:45:00 mmonkey systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 11 12:45:00 mmonkey systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I've check the related logs using WINSCP and the errors that I can find there for those are:

**nginx service**

```
2018/09/11 12:13:58 [emerg] 7261#7261: no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server.atomic.conf:3
```

The `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/service.atomix.conf` info is as follows:

```
Version=2.1
server
{
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name 192.168.1.88 mmonkey 0.0.0.0 127.0.0.1;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/server.atomic.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/server.atomic.error.log;
  index index.html index.php;

  client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
  send_timeout 5m;
  server_tokens off;

  location ~ /\.ht
  {
    deny all;
  }

  ##
  # Snippet Config
  ##

  include /etc/nginx/snippets/gzip.atomic.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/headers.atomic.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.atomic.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/proxy.atomic.conf;

  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.atomic.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/locations-enabled/*.atomic.conf;
}
```

I've tried to install a newer version of the VBOX Guest Additions however I can't mount a new ISO.  It is not recognized in the /media/cdrom/ hence I can't run the VBoxLinuxAdditions.run in order to trigger the installation.

Please help :) :) I do not want to recreate everything from scratch as it is a 60GB VDI :D :D